# Call parents constructor and prototype from child object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the methods to call constructor and prototype methods in JavaScript.

Here is my try:

```
function A() {
    this.getId = function() {
        console.log('A constructor - getId');
    }
}
A.prototype.getId = function() {
    console.log('A prototype - getId');
}
function B() {
    A.call(this);
    this.getId = function() {
        console.log('B constructor - getId');
    }
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.getId = function() {
    console.log('B prototype - getId');
}
var p = new A();
var q = new B();

p.getId()
//A constructor - getId 

q.getId()
//B constructor - getId

p.constructor.prototype.getId()
//A prototype - getId 

q.constructor.prototype.getId()
//B prototype - getId
```

Are last two ways are correct way to Call prototype methods?

How can I call parents constructor and prototype methods from child object q?

Comment: mind your Ps and Qs, you are re-defining these methods as you go along.

Comment: @dandavis Sure, I used it for simplicity here.

Comment: in general, you should not have to aim high or low, the beauty of prototypal is that you can pretend everything is an own property/method. you don't need a link between the two to achieve re-usability, and in fact, a link will make it ambiguous and confusing. you can just say B.prototype.getId.call(A) or vice-versa from anywhere.

Comment: @Yogesh: Do you understand why q.constructor.prototype.getId()
shows //A constructor - getId ?

Comment: You should [fix your inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) before trying to understand what is going on here. It would avoid a lot problems and confusion.

Comment: @Bergi Can you please edit the question. I am using new properly, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

> So, how can I get
>
> 'B prototype - getId' from q object

Because *q* is an instance of *B*. The *B* constructor assigns a *getId* method directly on the instance, so that's the one you get. If you were expecting the one on *B.prototype*, then you need to remove (or not assign) the one on the instance:

```
// delete getId on instance
delete q.getId; 

// Now get inherited getId
q.getId()  // B prototype - getId
```

Note that the *delete* operator only works on own properties, it won't delete properties on the `[[Prototype]]` chain.

> Are last two ways are correct way to
>
> 1. Call parents prototype method using p Parents constructor method using
> 2. q

"Correct" in that they work, though I wouldn't design it to work that way.

Comment: How can I call parents constructor and prototype methods from child object q?